# Why does my custom pin shows label only for the last pin in Xamarin Forms Maps?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer, xamarin.forms.maps

I implemented the custom map and custom pin as the example from docs.microsoft, but when I tap on a pin if its not the last one created pin then it cannot find the pin:

[image: Error]

The error appears here in the  Android Renderer

```
var customPin = GetCustomPin(marker);
                if (customPin == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
                }
```

customPin can't get the values

This is how I place the pins:

```
CustomPin pin = new CustomPin();
            pin.Type = PinType.Place;
            pin.Label = "Bus # 1";
            pin.Address = "394 Pacific Ave, San Francisco CA";
            pin.Name = "Xamarin";
            pin.Url = "url test";
            pin.Position = (new Position(9.934224393214128, -84.08272226354063));
            map.CustomPins = new List<CustomPin> { pin };
            map.Pins.Add(pin);
            map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(9.934224393214128, -84.08272226354063), Distance.FromMiles(1.0)));



            CustomPin pin2 = new CustomPin();
            pin2.Type = PinType.Place;
            pin2.Label = "Bus # 2";
            pin2.Address = "394 Pacific Ave, San Francisco CA";
            pin2.Name = "Xamarin";
            pin2.Url = "url test";
            pin2.Position = (new Position(9.932673627402988, -84.07538128629682));
            map.CustomPins = new List<CustomPin> { pin2 };
            map.Pins.Add(pin2);
            map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(9.932673627402988, -84.07538128629682), Distance.FromMiles(1.0)));
```

I believe the issue is here

```
map.CustomPins = new List<CustomPin> { pin2 };
```

because of the "new" but how can I make this different to add as many pin as I want?

**This is what I've tried**

```
List<CustomPin> CustomPinsList = new List<CustomPin>();
CustomPinsList.Add(pin2);
map.CustomPins.Add(CustomPinsList[1]);
```

and this

```
map.CustomPins.Add(pin);
```

Comment: you are using both `CustomPins` and `customPins`?

Comment: yeah, as I understand both are refering to the CustomPin class

Comment: where are you initializing `customPins`?  If you don't then it will be null and you will get a null ref exception.  I suspect that you only want `CustomPins`, but without seeing more code I can't say for sure.

Comment: customPins is initialized in the Android Custom Renderer "List<CustomPin> customPins;" code is the same as in here https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/main/CustomRenderers/Map/Droid/CustomMapRenderer.cs

Comment: well, then you need to start by figuring which line is causing the exception, and then which element of that line is null

Comment: customPins takes values in the renderer from CustomPins, but CustomPins is already null by that point

Comment: if you know that "CustomPins is already null" then why haven't you fixed it?

Comment: because I don't know in which part the values get lost, when adding the pin the map.CustomPins does have a value

Comment: welcome to the world of debugging.  You just have to work through it

Comment: I've been doing it for two days now. But yeah, I'll go on.

Comment: if you post the code somewhere I'll take a quick look

Comment: I found something so I changed the question,

Comment: every time you create a pin you are creating a new instance of `CustomPins` instead of adding to the existing instance

Comment: that's what I don't know how

Comment: `map.CustomPins.Add(pin2);`

Comment: Doesn't work, throws the null exception in that line

Comment: have you instantiated `CustomPins` before you try to use it?  Any object in C# needs to be instantiated before it can be accessed

Comment: `map.CustomPins = new List<CustomPin>();`.  You only need to do this **once**, then you can add pins to the list